# C# MD5 hash taking up no disk IO but is producing a hash

Tags: c#, hash

I find this quite odd. I have a utility I'm working on which will be pointed at a folder, index the folder with relative path / filename / filesize / md5 hash / some other things. If the md5 hashes don't match, it updates the hash in the database, backs the file up again, and continues on it's way with the rest of the files. This is primarily for backup purposes, but also me leaning.

The first time I ran the program aimed at some of my web projects it used disk IO and grabbed file handles, both visible in Process Hacker. However, the second time of running it (as in, I shut it down and restarted it), it doesn't appear to be taking up any disk IO, and only periodically grabs a handle. Yet, a hash is appearing.

The code which iterates over the files:

```
        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            try
            {
                string relativePath = path.Replace(@"Z:\99_Projects\web\de.com\", "");
                BackupFile backupFile = BackupFile.GetFile(relativePath, connection);
                string md5hash = "";
                long filesize = (new FileInfo(path)).Length;

                using (var file = File.OpenRead(path))
                {
                    md5hash = Hasher.ComputeMD5Hash(file);
                    //Console.WriteLine(md5hash);
                    if (backupFile == null)
                    {
                        BackupFile.NewBackupFile(relativePath, Path.GetFileName(path), md5hash, filesize, connection);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (backupFile.md5 != md5hash)
                            backupFile.flags = CoreLib.Utils.Backup.Enums.BackupFileFlags.CHANGED;
                        else
                            backupFile.flags = CoreLib.Utils.Backup.Enums.BackupFileFlags.UNCHANGED;

                        backupFile.filesize = filesize;
                        backupFile.md5 = md5hash;
                        backupFile.Save(connection);
                    }

                    file.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Access: " + Path.GetFileName(path));
            }
            catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("|E|");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("|EG|");
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

The code for the Hasher class as used, which is just really a small method wrapper for the cryptography MD5 hash calculator so I could reuse it (and other hash methods I stick in it) elsewhere in other code.

```
public class Hasher
{
    public static string ComputeMD5Hash(Stream stream)
    {
        string hash = "";
        using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            hash = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();                   
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

I've tried several things, including debugging the application and verified that it's actually opening up file streams and computing a hash. I've also had it print out the hash to the console, as shown by the commented out line under where it's computed, but even when it's printing it out it's showing no disk IO at all.

Comment: Most likely the file is being cached in memory, so there is no actual disk I/O. As far as not getting a handle, I suppose it could be getting the handle and releasing it so fast that your monitor doesn't have time to report it.

Comment: Sure it's not just the OS filesystem cache kicking in?

Comment: @ChrisJ was thinking that, but I'm not sure where to look to disable that for this or find out if that's what it's doing at least. Where might I look into that? Also, it could be grabbing them so fast due to the filesystem caching. It does show one, but very briefly, so that would make sense.

Comment: Well, I guess one way to test if it's the OS caching would be to try completely restarting, and as you are, watching the file I/O.

Comment: Well, I actually changed one of the files and watched the disk IO while it redid it. It had no disk IO, but picked up the new hash. It could be also that the polling rate of Process Hacker was not fast enough to pick up the IO on one simple .gitignore file, but the hash was updated in the DB. So it's at least detecting changes. I don't really think there's anything to fix, given that.

Comment: Process hacker could be watching 'after' the cache (which would be odd) or missing it. If not, well, try deleting the file, and see if it still works!

Comment: "I actually changed one of the files." And the file system cached the file when you saved it. And the actual disk I/O could happen at a much later time--when the OS gets around to flushing its cache to the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks as though it's simple file system cache mixed with Process Hacker's polling rate being too slow to pick up on it once cached. I changed a file, it detected the change but showed no measurable disk IO at all (which it does in bytes), so I'm assuming at this point it just didn't pick up on it due to how fast it was going.